# Anti CSRF session token script PHP logic issue

Tags: php, security, webforms

I feel like this is a logic issue. On page load I'm calling token.php which should set a session token and fill a hidden field with the same token.
When my webform is submitted it is comparing the tokens before sending the information to me. The intention is to prevent CSRF attacks. As I'm very new to PHP (and js, jQuery, HTML, coding and many other things) I can't find the error.

I am getting "token invalid" response. It should set the same token to both variables, and I'm handling a blank token with another error message.

In the head of my index.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('token.php').done(function(data) {
            $('input[name="token"]').val(data);
        }).fail();
        {
        //failure code goes here
        }
    });
</script>
```

**token.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
    if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    }
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
?>
```

**formsubmit.php**

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST['token'])) {
        if (hash_equals($_SESSION['token'], $_POST['token'])) {
            $emailbody = 'Name: '.$_POST['m_title'].' '.$_POST['m_firstname'].' '.$_POST['m_surname']."\n"
            .'Email: '.$_POST['m_email']."\n"
            .'Phone: '.$_POST['m_phone']."\n"
            .'D.O.B: '.$_POST['m_dob_day'].' '.$_POST['m_dob_month'].' '.$_POST['m_dob_year']."\n"          
            .'Postcode: '.$_POST['m_postcode']."\n"
            .'Lenders: '.$_POST['m_bank1'].','.$_POST['m_bank2'].','.$_POST['m_bank3'].','.$_POST['m_bank4'].','.$_POST['m_bank5'].','.$_POST['m_bank6'].','.$_POST['m_bank7'].','.$_POST['m_bank8'];               
            mail('**removed**', 'Web Lead', $emailbody);
            header('Location: **removed**.com/thankyou');
            exit();
        }   
        else {
            echo "token invalid";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "token blank";
    }
}
else {
    echo "invalid request";
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you really create an endpoint to set the token? Kind of defeats the purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning any informations from token.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['token']))
    $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
echo ($_SESSION['token']);
```

By the way, don't close `<?php` tag if you are only using php code in that page, that way, you avoid sending space/new lines characters as response.

In your jquery, the `fail()` method won't work as you expected because of a semicolon after it rather than an anonymous function call.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('token.php').done(function(data) {
            $('input[name="token"]').val(data);
        }).fail(function()
        {
            //failure code goes here
        });
    });
</script>
```

To handle the token stored in session, don't forget to add at the begining of formsubmit.php :

```
<?php 
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: I'm a little lost. The php tag and the semi colon on failure conditions I understand. 
I can see it generating the session token using echo, but how do I copy that into the hidden token filed back on index.html?

Comment: That hidden input has certainly an id, like `<input type="hidden" id="token_id" ...` you can assign it using `$('#token_id').val(data);`.

Comment: I was mistaken. Having done some fiddling I've found that the hidden field is correctly storing the value and the session token is reaching formsubmit.php blank. 
My issue must be cause by not storing the session token correctly or causing it to reset.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['token']);` and `var_dump($_SESSION['token']);` in formsubmit.php might help

Comment: Oh and by the way, don't forget `session_start();` in formsubmit.php